# How does this adding of two numbers works in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to assembly language and trying to understand a simple program which will add two nunbers and display the result.

```
section .data

message1 db "value=%d%d",10,0

 section .text
   global main
   extern printf
   main:
   mov eax, 55
   mov ebx, 45
   add eax,ebx
   push eax
   push ebx
   push message1
   call printf
   add esp, 8
   ret
```

Now output comes out is 45 100

After add eax ebx instruction result will be stored in eax register.

But now what happen in coming lines

```
 push eax   // push 100 on to stack

 push ebx   // push 45 on to stack

 push message1  // push "value=%d" on to stack // I m bit doubtful here
```

What I would like to know is what happen when "call printf" is executed??

What is the puspose of "add esp,8"??

Comment: Call printf will be exclusive to your own flavour of assembly language, popping or using the printing data pushed onto the stack. The add esp 8 bit makes the stack pointer jump to the correct location for the ret command. This pops the stack and jumps straight to the location. If it's the wrong value, the program rets to the wrong memory location and crashes. (you could try removing add esp,8 and see what happens)

Comment: With 3 parameters, should be `add esp, 12`. I like to write it as `add esp, 4 * 3` - makes it easy to change the number of parameters...

Comment: I guess you are right Frank.With 3 parameters it should be add esp 12 but in above case "call printf" is also pushing one parameter to stack which makes it add esp ,16. Would like to hear a word or two from your end on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `printf` librarymay be implemented in many ways, so it would be dangerous to assert that `ALL` `printf` routines will execute in the manner that `THIS` `printf` acts.

The sequence

push eax   // push 100 on to stack
   push ebx   // push 45 on to stack
   push message1  // push THE ADDRESS OF the message "value=%d" onto stack 
   call printf // push the RETURN ADDRESS to the stack

enters the `printf` routine with, reading the stack from the BOTTOM

1. The return address
2. A Pointer to the message
3. Some parameter values

So, `PRINTF` would most likely

1. `POP` the return address and save it
2. `POP` the pointer to the message
3. `MOV`e the `STACK POINTER` to a register or save it

Then it can go about its task - using the pointer to the message, write each character out until it encounters a keystring like `%d` which says 'print something as a decimal. So it `POP`s the next value from the stack (45, as pushed in `ebx`), formats that as a decimal and prints it, then continues with the `printf` string.

Another `%d` - the 100 pushed from `eax`, then continue - until you find the `0` byte indicating end-of-string.

All `printf` needs to do now to return is to restore the `stack pointer` from wherever it was stored, and return to the return address - wherever that's been stored.

And when it returns, the stack is restored to exactly what it was when the `printf` was called - and at that time, `EBX` and `EAX` had been `PUSH`ed. Each is 4 bytes, so the `stack pointer` needs to be adjusted by 8 bytes to remove the data stored by these two `PUSH` instructions.

So - why do it that way - why not simply allw `PRINTF` to adjust the stack - which it could, since it knows it's removed 8 bytes for display (2*%d)?

Well, in essence, it could - but suppose the message only contained one %d - or 3 - or something that consumed something OTHER than 8 bytes? On return, the `stack-pointer` would contain an unexpected value - which depends on how `PRINTF` interprets a string. Very difficult to pull assembler tricks like overwriting parts of messages withou being extraordinarily careful. As it's written, the `printf` function always acts in a predictable manner, returning having popped off the message address, regardless of any other consideration. Up to the programmer to properly deal with the stack contents.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your kind response ,One thing I would lile to know push message1 will push the address of message1 in memeory at where  string constant "value=%d" is stored,is it safe to say that? and how printf and PRINTF is different

Comment: The value pushed is the address of the first byte of Message1, known as a pointer to message1. There is no difference between `printf` and `PRINTF` as far as I'm concerned. Most assemblers will allow either - I tend to capitalise for emphasis. Best to keep consistent though - especially in a learning environment.

Comment: Peter just one small query again ,Our PRINTF will be poping out the stack content and move the SP to correct position and over top it we explicitly calling add esp,12 ,Won't it take the ESP tp wrong position??and where is POPED the return address by printf is going to store?

Comment: Hmm - looking again at your code, and after a few hours' sleep, I'd suggest that the stack pointer `IS NOT` being changed by the `CALL PRINTF`. The adding of `8` to `ESP` in the original listing *should* be adding `12` - 4 each for the push of `EBX`and `EAX` and 4 for `the pointer to MESSAGE1`. That would make more sense. The part of the code responsible for `PLACING` the data onthe stack would also be responsible for `REMOVING` it. The `PRINTF` routine would simply set a pointer to data on the stack which would be ESP+4 on entry to `PRINTF` 4 bytes for the return address:the last item PUSHed

Comment: Thanks Peter again,so is it safe to assume Call PRINTF would be using some other register to store the stack address not the ESP,and why we are not adding 16 to ESP since return address is also pushed on to stack.