# Why this Code causing infinte loop in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a small piece of code in Assemby which is basiclly run through a loop and print values in reverse order but when I run, it goes to infinte loop.Below is the code .

```
section .data
x db "value=%d"
section .text
global main
extern printf
main:
mov eax, 10
well_done:
push eax
push x

call printf
add esp,8
dec eax
cmp eax ,0
jnz well_done
ret
```

Comment: There's a push but no pop?

Comment: `eax` is caller-save in cdecl, `printf` is probably killing its value

Comment: @kerrek May I know why pop is required in this particular case .

Comment: I don't know - I'm not claiming to understand it, I just noticed the asymmetry.

Comment: Like harold said, the return value for printf is stored in eax

Comment: So @pastsa, should I use other register or what??

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: You're not _restoring_ the value from the stack after the `printf`, though. harold is 100% correct.

Comment: @FrankH Could you please let me know how in code I can achieve it.

Comment: do `add esp,4` followed by `pop eax` instead of your `add esp,8`.

Comment: @KerrekSB The `add esp,8` pops the function arguments from the stack.

Comment: You can't restore it from this anyway, a function may modify its arguments - that's not overly common, but you can't really rely on it. You can either `push eax` twice (and pop it after the call, obviously), or use a callee-save register like `ebx`

Comment: One more clarification would like to have as I m new to assembly,after pushing the value to stack would eax resigter value is cleared?

Comment: In your given code, put the count in `ecx`, and copy `ecx` to `eax` before pushing `eax`. `dec` and compare `ecx`.

Comment: @rajraj `ecx` is also caller-save and is most likely also trashed by `printf` (as an aside, you might as well push it directly, without moving to eax)

Comment: @Harold, couple of point I would like to know from your end,1).Whenever call printf pushes the return address to stack ,will it alter the ESP??(I guess no) 2).Pushing a value to stack like push eax ,will cut and paste the value from eax to stack or its copy and paste from eax to stack.

Comment: The return value isn't pushed, it goes in `eax` (well, in most cases). Pushing copies the value, in general there's not really a "cut" in x86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's too long for a comment, I'll just put it here: what I meant with using a callee-save register is something like this

```
section .data
x db "value=%d"

section .text
global main
extern printf

main:
  mov ebx, 10
well_done:
  push ebx
  push x
  call printf
  add esp, 8
  dec ebx
  jnz well_done
  ret
```

Note that usually using `ebx` means that you should save `ebx` on entry and restore it on exit, but because this is `main` we get away with not doing that.

Comment: to the point "The return value isn't pushed, it goes in eax (well, in most cases)",I believe where ever call printf is executed first thing it do is to push return to stack but not alter the esp ,something which I was told by Peter Wright in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960337/how-does-this-adding-of-two-numbers-works-in-assembly" in the answer to this question.Would you like to say something on the same.

Comment: Oh the return *address*, yes, a `call` pushes that and then jump. A `ret` pops the address* and jumps to it.  * it pops something and interprets it as an address, regardless of whether or not it's actually a valid address.

Comment: What about altering the ESP??Will call pushes alter the esp? and final point why really in your code add esp,8 is required, anyway ebx has value 10 which we can use it without point esp to right location.

Comment: `call` and `ret` change `esp` yes. `add esp, 8` is required to get rid of the arguments that you gave `printf` (unlike in stdcall, in cdecl the caller cleans the stack). You can get away with not cleaning the stack for a while, but then the last `ret` will pop the wrong thing and probably crash. If the loop was longer, stack overflow could become an issue as well.

Comment: Thanks Again Harold for your kind inputs,it will help me a lot going forward.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function you must be sure which registers are used. If you call a C function `eax` can be used for whatever the function needs it, so you must `push eax` before you execute the function, and after it returned you can `pop` it.

```
section .data
x db "value=%d"
section .text
global main
extern printf
main:
mov eax, 10
well_done:
push eax   <- save the counter
push eax   <- argument for printf
push x

call printf
add esp,8   <- clears the stack with the arguments for printf
pop eax   <- restore the counter
dec eax
cmp eax ,0
jnz well_done
ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone for the help .This is how I did as sugested by Harold.Thanks Harold

```
section .data
x db "value=%d"
section .text
global main
extern printf
main:
mov ebx, 10
well_done:
push ebx
push x

call printf
add esp,4
pop ebx
dec ebx
cmp ebx ,0
jnz well_done
ret
```

Comment: Anyways @Devolus using register eax also working fine for me,replace ebx with eax makes no difference.

Comment: This is actually not how I intended it, I meant using `ebx` and then *not restoring it*, you don't have to restore it `printf` itself has to restore `ebx`.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar, Yes, I know. I didn't know about that something like this callee save convention existed.